# Send email periodically with systemd

Tags: systemd, mutt, systemd-timer

I'd like to use [systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) to send emails periodically to remind me of certain things like anniversaries or filing taxes.

I send my regular emails with [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/); it would be nice if I could reuse that to send the automated emails, and not having to install additional software like [Sendmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail).

I'm on Arch Linux 4.18.5, `systemctl --version` says systemd 239.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a systemd service file at `~/.config/systemd/user/send-mail.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sends mail that reminds me of an anniversary

[Service]
; The l flag for bash creates a login shell so Mutt can access our environment variables which contain configuration
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc "echo \"$(whoami) created this message on $(date) to remind you about...\" | mutt -s \"Don't forget...\" you@domain.com"
```

You can test whether sending mail works by executing

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload && systemctl --user start send-mail.service
```

This should send an email to `you@domain.com`.

Then, create a timer at `~/.config/systemd/user/send-mail.timer` with these contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for writing mail to myself to remind me of anniversaries

[Timer]
; Trigger the service yearly on September 5th
OnCalendar=*-09-05
; Send a mail immediately when the date has passed while the machine was shut down
Persistent=true
AccuracySec=1us
; Set the timer to every ten seconds (for testing)
; OnCalendar=*:*:0/10

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Note that the timer's contents don't reference the service. It still works because the service and the timer have the same name apart from their suffixes `.service` and  `.timer`. If you want to name timer and service differently, use `Unit=` in the timer's `[Timer]` section.

Make your timer start at boot with

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload && systemctl --user enable send-mail.timer
```

You should be able to see the timer now with `systemctl --user list-timers --all`.

To start the timer, do

```
systemctl --user start send-mail.timer
```

To check how systemd interprets your dates, you can use `systemd-analyze calendar *:0/2` or `systemd-analyze calendar quarterly`.
Also, check out the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html) on systemd's time format.